# Sending data between viewControllers using protocol+delegate in swift 4

Tags: xcode, swift4

I'm a beginner with Swift and I'm struggling to understand the way the variables are send between page_1  and page_2 using delegate and protocols.

I have a 2-page application: ViewController1.swift and ViewController2.swift
- on page 1 (ViewController1.swift) I have a textbox (TextBoxControl)  and a button.
- on page 2 (ViewController2.swift) I have a label and a button

I want to send text in thextbox from page_1 to page_2 and print it in page_2.

The problem is that the delegated is always nil (it prints on the console
... print ("Delegate is nil"). )

Technologies: XCODE Version 9.4.1, swift 4

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show some code that you tried

Comment: Can you share your code??

Answer (score 2):

If you want send data from ViewController1 to ViewController2 then simply follow these step.

Step 1:

Set a variable in ViewController2 : like

```
var strValue : String?
```

step 2:

Write this code in button action ViewController1

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
destination.strValue = yourTextBoxControl.text
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```

step 3:

In ViewController2 class you can easily get this value like :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(strValue)
}
```

Thanks hope it will helps you.